# Test a UITableView, which lists the video library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm working on a UITableView, which displays all the videos and movies from the device's video library. Is there a way for me to test the result in the iphone/ipad simulator?

Because there is no video library in the simulator, I can't see wether it works or not.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To take Picture, video and select an image from photo library, `UIImagePickerController` will help you.

[Ref: UIImagePickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html)

To take picture and video, `UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureMode` has to be set properly.

Also the `sourceType` needs to be set as we required. See `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType`.

And also [read this official documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/CameraAndPhotoLib_TopicsForIOS/Articles/TakingPicturesAndMovies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010406)

Comment: Hi, thank you. But I'm actually asking if there is a way for me to test the result in the simulator. So that I can see if things are working on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

To test on simulator you need to have some video on the simulator. Here's the link may help you to have video on your simulator:

[insert video on simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571656/iphone-how-do-i-add-videos-to-ipad-simulator/3046699#3046699)